# How to get spring security oauth2 client details from mongodb instead of inmemory

Tags: mongodb, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am current using spring security oauth2 and configured the oauth2 as using the clients from inMemory, how to get the client id/client secret from mongodb and use mongodb as the store for the client details and how to configure spring oauth2 using that.

One approach I was thinking was to use mongo template to read the client details and configure the inMemory client details using those values. Will this be a way to go about this?

Is there another way to get client details from mongodb and configure the clients for spring security oauth2?

Answer (score -2):

Try
[this link](https://malike.github.io/Spring-Security-OAuth2.html). You will have to create custom client details storage along with custom access and refresh token implementation.